# Colimit of submodules

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, limits-colimits

I was going through a proof in the paper "Local unit versus local projectivity", where I came across the fact that for an $R$ module $P$ if $P = \operatorname{colim}\limits_{i\in I} P_i$ where $I$ is a directed set and $P_i$'s are finitely generated projective submodules of $P$ then for each $x \in P$ there exists some $k \in I$ such that $x \in P_k$. 
   I don't have a very good knowledge on colimit in category theory. Any help in this matter would be highly appreciated.

Comment: An intuitive explanation is that a colimit of submodules is basically the same as the union.

Comment: Sorry. It's supposed to be $x \in P_k$. Corrected that.

Comment: This assertion has nothing to do with the $P_i$s being finitely generated projective.

Comment: This isn't true as you've stated it. $R \oplus R$ is the coproduct of submodules $R \oplus 0$ and $0 \oplus R$, but $(1,1)$ is not in either.

Comment: So, did you mean for $I$ to be a filtered category? Or a directed set if that's how you think of things? Alternatively, is $P_i$ supposed to range over *all* finitely generated projective submodules (and inclusions between them) rather than just some subdiagram of them?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Can you please help me get to it or refer any book?

Comment: @Hurkyl Good points. I automatically thought of this as a filtered limit, since that would make the assertion true. We will need the OP to clarify it.

Comment: @Hurkyl $I$ is supposed to be a directed set and $(P_i)$ is a subcollection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $I$ be a directed set and $\varphi_{ij}:M_i\to M_j$ with $i,j\in I$ and $i\leq j$ be a diagram of $R$-modules that's $\varphi_{ii}=\mathrm{id}|M_i$ and $\varphi_{jk}\circ\varphi_{ij}=\varphi_{ik}$ for $i\leq j\leq k$.
Let $\displaystyle M\cong\lim_\rightarrow M_i$ be a colimit with co-cone $\varkappa_i:M_i\to M$ so that $\varkappa_i=\varkappa_j\circ\varphi_{ij}$ for $i\leq j$.
Then $M$ is union of the images of $\varkappa_i$, that's
$$M=\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathrm{Im}(\varkappa_i)$$

For prove this, let $N=\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathrm{Im}(\varkappa_i)$.
Then $N$ is a $R$-submodule of $M$, for if $x,y\in N$ then $x=\varkappa_i(x')$ and $y=\varkappa_j(y')$ for some $x'\in M_i$ and $y'\in M_j$ with $i,j\in I$.
Since $I$ is directed, there exists $k\in I$ such that $i\leq k$ and $j\leq k$.
Consequently, $x=\varkappa_i(x')=\varkappa_k\circ\varphi_{ik}(x')$ and $y=\varkappa_j(y')=\varkappa_k\circ\varphi_{jk}(y')$ hence $x,y\in\mathrm{Im}(\varkappa_k)$, thus are defined $x\pm y\in N$ and $ax\in N$ for $a\in R$ by means of $R$-module structure on $\mathrm{Im}(\varkappa_k)\subseteq N$.

In order to prove $M=N$ consider the projection $\pi:M\to M/N$ and for $a\in R$ the homothety $\omega_a:x\in M/N\mapsto ax:M/N\to M/N$.
Then $\omega_a\circ\pi\circ\varkappa_i=0=\pi\circ\varkappa_i$ for each $i\in I$ hence by universal property (uniqueness) $\omega_a\circ\pi=\pi$, that's $ax=x$ for each $a\in R$ and $x\in M/N$, that's $(a-1)x=0$.
Thus $x=(a-1)x=0$ for each $x\in M/N$ and this proves $M/N=\{0\}$ that's $M=N$ as required.

Comment: So the proof shows that each for each $m \in M$ there exists $k \in I$ such that $m \in$ Im($\varkappa_k$) but if I'm not wrong then $\varkappa_i$'s are not necessarily injective. Then can we say anything about $m$ belonging to even an isomorphic copy of $M_k$? Also is the commutativity of the ring required at any point of the proof?

Comment: You can say that for each $m\in M$ there exists $i\in I$ and $x\in M_i$ such that $m=\kappa_i(x)$. The ring $R$ is commutative in order to make $\omega_a$ an $R$-module homomorphism.

Comment: Without any further assumption on $\varphi_{ij}$, you can say nothing about $\kappa_i$ and $x\in M_i$.

Comment: Ok can't we just consider the trivial morphism $\psi : M \rightarrow M/N$ given by $x \mapsto 0+N$ for all $x \in M$ so that $\psi \circ\varkappa_i = 0 = \pi\circ\varkappa_i$ for each $i \in I$. Hence by universal property $\pi = \psi$ i.e., $x+N = 0+N$ for all $x \in M$ implying $M \subseteq N$.

Comment: Yes, this is a better choice making the proof valid also in a non-commutative case.